# Cant find pyodbc driver despite install

Tags: drivers, python, mssql, odbc

I have `pyodbc` installed and I am trying to connect to a server, but `pyodbc` can't find the drivers. I did the following:

1. Installed `pyodbc` using `pip`:

   ```
   pip install pyodbc
   ```
2. Followed the [Microsoft instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-2017).
3. Ran a test script:

   ```py
   import pyodbc 

   print(pyodbc.drivers())
   ```

   which returned an empty array.

What else do I need to do? I'm running the script in a Jupyter Notebook inside an Anaconda Python install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having same issue. The only workaround I found was to pass the driver file location to the connection request. But the connection/bandwidth is extremely slow when trying to query using `pyodbc` (compared with using SQL Ops Studio).

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

driver = '/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so' # Change this to where FreeTDS installed the driver library!

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    driver = driver,
    TDS_Version = '7.3', 
    server = <tunneled server>,
    port = 1433,
    uid = <sql_user_id>,
    pwd = <sql_password>)

crsr = conn.cursor()
table = pd.read_sql(<sql statement>, conn)
crsr.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: In my case my driver was in the following location in ubuntu18.04LTS /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.1.1 And I used the above suggestion and it worked perfectly.